# What can it mean if an object is scriptable?

Tags: language-agnostic, object, scriptable

Exactly what the title says. Note, this is not about "[subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-scriptable-or-not)" objects.

Comment: There wasn't any question about what scriptable objects are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scriptable object is an object that records the operations done to it and it can store them as a "script" which can be replayed.

For example, see: [Application Scripting Framework](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/AppTools/trunk/docs/source/appscripting/Introduction.rst)

Comment: Community-wiki owned because I don't give a space-faring frak about reputation.

Comment: Ranking on google and reputation on SO are better than gold, my friend :)

Comment: @Federico Ramponi: I am not sure if "you are with us or with them" ;), but your comment is oh-so-very-true.

Answer (score 2):

It means *nothing* in Python as scriptable objects are provided by Enthought's [Traits](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/Traits) module.

From [Application Scripting Framework](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/AppTools/trunk/docs/source/appscripting/Introduction.rst), which mentions that:

> A scriptable type is a sub-type of
>   HasTraits that has scriptable methods
>   and scriptable traits.

And goes on to define:

> A scriptable object is an instance of
>   a scriptable type.

Traits is not part of the standard library but it *is* distributed as part of the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php).

Please don't confuse the two.

Comment: Well, seems the question was too language-specific. Anyway, I don't know why you deem necessary to explicitly say that traits is not part of the standard library.

Comment: Because the question would be better worded as "What does it mean _IN TRAITS_ if an object is scriptable?" As it, you seem to imply that "scriptable objects" are a part of Python, when this just isn't the case.