# What does it mean for an object to be unscriptable?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I don't know what's going on here... I just want to check the value of a model field and then update it accordingly... any help or insight is appreciated!

model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    beta = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

view:

```
from internal.accounts.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
@login_required    
def beta_testers(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_profile = user.get_profile()

    count = UserProfile.objects.filter(beta='1').count()

    if count < 50 and not user_profile['beta']:
        user_profile['beta'] = '1'
        user_profile.save()
```

error:

```
TypeError at /utilities/beta-signup/
'UserProfile' object is unsubscriptable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/utilities/beta-signup/?x=1&y=15
Django Version: 1.2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'UserProfile' object is unsubscriptable
Exception Location: C:/django\internal\cms_helper\views.py in beta_testers, line 284
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, what does it mean if an object is subscriptable or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error is "unSUBscriptable".  Your user_profile object isn't a dictionary.  Use `user_profile.beta`, not `user_profile['beta']`.

Comment: Oh yes, this must be it. Thank you.

Comment: Why is that so, anyway? Is there a way to make Django provide that functionality?

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively, you can use a string with [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(user_profile, 'beta', False)
```

False is the default value; which, in your case would work with checking if the value is set or not.  I found this very helpful, so I thought I would post this solution, even though the question was asked years ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

---

> Method One

```
model_name.object.filter(column_name='value').last
```

---

> Method Two

This error happens when you tries to insert a model object in text filed