# Django model.foreignKey and return self.text errors

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So I'm working on the model.py in Django and i'm getting 2 pylint errors.
I don't understand why? is this an issue with pylint or something i'm doing wrong in my code.

```
E1120:No value for argument 'on_delete' in constructor call    
E1136:Value 'self.text' is unsubscriptable
```

- The first is on line 19, in Entry
     topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
- The second is on line 24 self.text[:50]

If I remove the entry class the code works

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
"""A topic the user is learning about"""
text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
"""Something specific learned about a topic"""
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
text = models.TextField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "entries"

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617674/what-does-it-mean-for-an-object-to-be-unscriptable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was ForeignKey in Django 1.9 required 1 positional argument in Django 2.0 ForeignKey 2 required positional argument

```
  topic = models.ForeignKey("Topic", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. How did you resolve the "self.text is unsubscriptable" issue? This answer does not resolve that problem.

Comment: I removed the set number and left it blank. Not ideal but it worked.

Comment: I see you're learning from 'Python Crash Course'. Great choice. Used it myself. The reason `return self.text[:50] + "..."` isn't working is because Python doesn't recognize `self.text` as a String (because it's really a `models.TextField`) so it doesn't know how to interpret `[:50]` or how to concatenate it with `"..."`. When you get rid of the other stuff it knows to just cast it as a String, that's why that works. To get it to work as intended try `return str(self.text)[:50] + "..."`. That way `self.text` is now represented in its String form and you can perform String operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of second issue is you missed the command after the command `python manage.py makemigrations [appname]`, the missing command is `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, we should use `on_delete=models.PROTECT`.

By default Django uses `on_delete=models.CASCADE` but this is not secure if object deleted accidentally.

In that case there would be no notification of deleted objects so it would be ideal to use models.PROTECT.