# 'WSGIRequest' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, html, django

I'm getting this error in this function in my views.py file. It's confusing because I don't know what 'WSGIRequest' is or why it's giving me problems. I know I have a variable called "newUser" because when I take out that one line the print(request.POST) line prints it out.

def AddNewUser(request):

```
a=AMI()
if(request.method == "POST"):
    print(request.POST)
    print(request["newUser"])
csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response("ac/AddNewUser.html", csrfContext)
```

`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[It means that WSGIRequest does not implement `__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not). You are trying to treat the `HttpRequest` object like a dictionary but it's not. If you want to access this newUser variable use the POST object, which implements a dictionary-like interface:

```
request.POST['newUser']
```

[You'd do well to peruse the Django docs in situations like this.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)