# Python: How to deal with non-subscriptable objects?

Tags: python, methods, dictionary, subscript

I've read [a thread on what a (non)subscriptable object is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) but it doesn't tell me what i can do about it.

I have a code calling a `mypost` private module. The aim is to set up mail accounts and to do this i create `MailAccounts()` objects defined in the `mypost` module. Quantity of accounts and their respective details are described in a configuration file. When the application starts, it collects account information and stores it in a dictionary, the structure of which is: `accounts = {service : { <MailAccounts Object at xxxxx> : {username : myusername, password : mypassword}}}` where `service` can be "gmail" and where `MailAccounts` is the class defined in the `mypost` module.
So far so good. When however i want to setup the account, i need to call its method: `MailAccounts.setupAccount(username, password)`. I do this by iterating each MailAccount object of the dictionary and ask to run the method:

```
for service in accounts:
        for account in accounts[service]:
            account.setupAccount(account['username'], account['password'])
```

But as you may have guessed it didn't work, Python returns:

`TypeError: 'MailAccount' object is not subscriptable`

If i create the same account manually however it works:

```
account = MailAccount()
account.setupAccount('myusername', 'mypassword')
```

Now i believe it has something to do with the fact that my `<MailAccount Object at xxxx>` is a dictionary key right? That makes it non-subscriptable (whatever that may mean)?

No what exactly does this mean to be non-subscriptable? What does it imply in this example? And of course: how can i solve / bypass this in this case?

Thanks,
Benjamin :)

Comment: Can you show us the code where `accounts` is populated, removing any sensitive info as needed?

Comment: @onteria: i have my answer now, do you mind if i skip your request? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to fix it is to use dictionaries properly.

```
for service in accounts:
        for account, creds in accounts[service].iteritems():
            account.setupAccount(creds['username'], creds['password'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the code you propose, but i don't really understand what difference it really makes to Python? Could you explain please?

Comment: If you want the technical explanation, then a "subscriptable object" is one whose class defines one or more of the `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, and `__delitem__()` methods. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Comment: @Benjamin: Always use `iterkeys`, `itervalues` and `iteritems` explicitly and you'll avoid confusion as to what you're getting from the dict. In your original code, `account` is a MailAccount instance (a key), not a dict (a value).

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Oh, i see! So the problem is not the method but what object i request the method from or what i feed to the method :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you iterate over a dictionary, you get the keys of that dictionary, not the items.

```
>>> x = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
>>> for item in x:
...     print(item)
... 
a
b
```

If you want to iterate over the values, do this:

```
>>> for item in x.values():
...     print(item)
... 
1
2
```

There is also an `items` method, for both keys and values at the same time:

```
>>> for item in x.items():
...     print(item)
... 
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
```