# TypeError: 'Monitor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

i've something in my head but it doesn't success
I've a node. On a node, we can attach monitors.
Then i've :

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.components = []
        self.monitors = []

class Monitor(object):

    def __init__(self, platform_id):
        self.platform_id = platform_id
```

I receive a list of monitors from a server and all these monitors if they are not linked to the node, has to be:

```
def get_or_create_monitor(self, monitors):
        node_monitors = self.node.monitors
        for m in monitors:
            if m['id'] not in [m.platform_id for m in node_monitors]:
                monitor = Monitor(m['id'])

                node_monitors.append(monitor)
```

the problem is the console response when i launch this function: TypeError: 'Monitor' object is not subscriptable

Where am i wrong ? I cannot have something like node.monitors = [, ] ?

Comment: looks like `self.node.monitors` is returning a `Monitor` object. Not a queryset

Comment: `if m['id'] not in [m.platform_id for m in node_monitors]` is *probably* more efficiently written `if any(m['id'] == x.platform_id for x in node_monitors)`.

Comment: raise Exception(type(self.node.monitors)) returns me Exception: <type 'list'> and not an instance

Comment: You need to change m['id'] to m.id, probably. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not

Answer (score 1):

i guess i'm the worst developer !
m variable is defines 2 times, once in for m in monitors, a twice in [m.platform_id for m in node_monitors] ...

then problem solved when replacing of one of these m