# What Is Subscriptable?

Tags: python

```
exxy = ['mix', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'xanadu', 'apple']

pleasework = []
ten = []

for s in exxy:
    if s[0] == 'x':
        pleasework.insert[0, s]
    else:
        ten.append[s]

pleasework.sort()
ten.sort()

pleasework.append(ten)

print pleasework
```

I keep getting an error that says that object is not subscriptable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jerrywalker/Desktop/CompSci/Programming/Programming_Resources/Python/idle.py", line 10, in <module>
    ten.append[s]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not really sure what this means.  I've just started Python yesterday... I'm sure it's something in the code that I'm not doing right, because even when I change the name of my variables around the error is the same.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not

Answer (score 4):

"Subscriptable" means that you're trying to access an element of the object. In the following:

```
ten.append[s]
```

you're trying to access element `s` of `ten.append`. Since you want to call it as a function/method instead, you need to use parens:

```
ten.append(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined two lines with the wrong syntax:

It shouldn't be:

```
pleasework.insert[0, s]
ten.append[s]
```

But rather:

```
pleasework.insert(0, s)
ten.append(s)
```

`ten.append(s)` is a list method and you cannot try to get a element `s` of `ten.append(s)`.

Even assuming you were trying to do something like `ten[s]` it would still return a error because `s` has to be the index *(which is a integer)* of the element you want