# Python "Type error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, encryption

My (recently fixed) code is as follows:

```
cryptograph = {"a":"b", "b":"c", "c":"d", 'd': 'e', 'e':'f', 'f':'g', 'g':'h', 'h':'i', 'i':'j', 'j':'k', 'k':'l', 'l':'m', 'm':'n', 'n':'o', 'o':'p', 'p':'q', 'q':'r', 'r':'s', 's':'t', 't':'u', 'u':'v','v':'w', 'w':'x', 'x':'y', 'y':'z', 'z':'a', ' ': ' ', '.':',', ',':'.', '"':"'", "'":'"', '<':'>', '>':'<', '0':'1', '9':'2', '8':'3', '7':'4', '6':'5', '5':'6', '4':'7', '3':'8', '2':'9', '1':'0'}

def encrypt (string):
    string = string.lower()
    length = len(string)
    toBeTranslated = splitter(string)
    translated = ''

    for letter in toBeTranslated:
        translated = translated + cryptograph[letter]
    print(translated)

def decrypt (string):
    string = string.lower()
    length = len(string)
    toBeTranslated = splitter(string)    
    translated = ''

    for letter in toBeTranslated:
        letter = 
        translated = translated + list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index[letter]]



def splitter (string):
    rotation = 0
    stringLength = len(string)
    charList = []
    for _ in range(stringLength):
        charList.append(string[rotation])
        rotation = rotation + 1
    return charList
```

I am trying to create a simple cryptograph application, and have run into a problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    decrypt('hi')
  File "C:\Users\WILLARD\Desktop\encryption.py", line 20, in decrypt
    letter = list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index[letter]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I have Googled it to no avail.

I believe the problem may lie in that i try to find a dict key using a value:

```
list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index[letter]]
```

Funny thing is, I tested that line using the interpreter, and it worked fine.

Comment: try `.index(letter)` instead of `.index[letter]`.

Comment: [In Python, what does it mean if an object is subscriptable or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Comment: Also, inside this loop `for letter in toBeTranslated:` you seem to have this: `letter =`.  You aren't assigning anything to letter. You should clean that one up as well.

Comment: As the error says: you're trying to subscript (meaning `[]`) a method (`list().index`), which is nonsense/doesn't work.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, i didn't notice that syntax error. thanks.

Comment: So, your code is working now, right? Voting to close as "simple typographical error"

Comment: BTW, `string` is not a great variable name, since it's the name of a standard module. It won't hurt your current code, but it can be a little confusing to people reading your code. And if you _do_ decide to import the string module, having a `string` variable may cause mysterious bugs.

Comment: Also, instead of `translated = translated + cryptograph[letter]` you can do `translated += cryptograph[letter]`

Comment: @PM2Ring never knew about the += function. Does it do the same thing as "variable = variable + otherVariable"?

Comment: @mrdorkface: It's called an [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements). From the docs: "An augmented assignment expression like `x += 1` can be rewritten as `x = x + 1` to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the augmented version, `x` is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead."

Comment: (cont) With immutable objects (eg, strings,  numbers, or tuples) `a+=b` _does_ create a new object, but with mutable objects (eg lists) it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, that will help me keep my code much cleaner than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index[letter]]

try instead:

```
list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index(letter)]
```