# python maze using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, maze

I want to solve a maze using recursion. The program opens a text file like this one:

```
10 20
1 1 
10 20
-----------------------------------------
|     |     | |     | | |       |     | |
|-+ +-+-+ +-+ + +-+ + + +-+-+ +-+-+ + + |
|         |       |     | | | |   | |   |
| + +-+ + + +-+-+-+ + + + + + +-+ + + + |
| | |   |     |     | |     |       | | |
| +-+-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+-+-+ +-+ + +-+-+ +-|
| | | |       |   | |         | |   |   |
| + + +-+ +-+-+ + + + +-+ +-+ + + + +-+ |
|     |     |   | |     | |   |   | | | |
|-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+ +-+-+ +-|
| |   |   |     |     |     |   | | | | |
| +-+-+ +-+-+ +-+ + +-+-+ +-+ +-+ + + + |
|       |     | | |   |   | | | |       |
|-+ +-+ + + +-+ +-+-+ + +-+ + + +-+ +-+ |
|   | | | |     | | | | | | | |   | | | |
|-+ + +-+ + + + + + +-+ + + + + +-+-+ + |
|       | | | |     |     |             |
| + + +-+ + +-+-+-+ + +-+ + + +-+-+ +-+ |
| | |     | |           | | | |     |   |
-----------------------------------------
```

The first line of the file is the size of the maze(10 20), the second line is the starting point(1 1), and the third line is the exit(10, 20). I want to mark the correct path with "*". This is what my code looks like:

EDIT: I change some of the code in the `findpath()` funtion, and now I dont get any errors but the maze is empty, the path('*') is not 'drawn' on the maze.

```
class maze():    
    def __init__(self, file):

        self.maze_list = []

        data= file.readlines()

        size = data.pop(0).split()  # size of maze

        start = data.pop(0).split() # starting row and column; keeps being 0 because the previous not there anymore
        self.start_i = start[0]  # starting row
        self.start_j = start[1]  # starting column

        exit = data.pop(0).split()   # exit row and column 
        self.end_i = exit[0]
        self.end_j = exit[1]

        for i in data:  
            self.maze_list.append(list(i[:-1])) # removes \n character off of each list of list
        print(self.maze_list) # debug


    def print_maze(self):

        for i in range(len(self.maze_list)):
            for j in range(len(self.maze_list[0])):  
                print(self.maze_list[i][j], end='')                         
            print()

def main():

    filename = input('Please enter a file name to be processed: ') # prompt user for a file


    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r')
    except:                     # if a non-existing file is atempted to open, returns error 
        print("File Does Not Exist")
        return  

    mazeObject = maze(file)
    mazeObject.print_maze() # prints maze

    row = int(mazeObject.start_i)
    col = int(mazeObject.start_j)   

    findpath(row, col, mazeObject)  # finds solution route of maze if any

def findpath(row, col, mazeObject):

    if row == mazeObject.end_i and col == mazeObject.end_j: # returns True if it has found the Exit of the maze
        mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] = ' ' # to delete wrong path
        return True

    elif mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] == "|": # returns False if it finds wall 
        return False

    elif mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] '-': # returns False if it finds a wall 
    return False

    elif mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] '+': # returns False if it finds a wall 
        return False    

    elif mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] '*': # returns False if the path has been visited
        return False

    mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] = '*'   # marks the path followed with an *   

    if ((findpath(row + 1, col, mazeObject)) 
        or (findpath(row, col - 1, mazeObject)) 
        or (findpath(row - 1, col, mazeObject)) 
        or (findpath(row, col + 1, mazeObject))):    # recursion method
        mazeObject.maze_list[row][col] = ' '  # to delete wrong path
        return True
    return False
```

So now my question is, where is the error? I mean the program just prints out the maze without the solution. I want to fill the correct path with "*".

Comment: What exactly is your question? Look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) for the meaning of your error. That may give you a clue how to fix it. :)

Comment: That error means that you are trying to access an object of class maze by numeric index, for example `maze[1]`, when what you want is `maze.maze_list[1]`. The object itself is not subscriptable, because it doesn't have a `__getitem__` method, unlike types such as lists, strings and tuples.

Comment: @puqeko ok, I think I understood that, I updated my question. I fixed the code and don't get errors now but the path still won't show in the maze

Comment: It will not fix your logic, but printing the maze  _after_ you call `findpath` is a good start. Also, you are missing some `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I see several errors. You do not handle the entry and exit row/column pairs correctly. (10,20) is correct for this maze, if you assume that every other row, and every other column, is a grid line. That is, if the `|` and `-` characters represent infinitely thin lines that have occasional breaks in them, much like traditional maze drawings.

You'll need to multiple/divide by two, and deal with the inevitable fencepost errors, in order to correctly translate your file parameters into array row/column values.

Next, your `findpath` function is confused:

First, it should be a method of the class. It accesses internal data, and contains "inner knowledge" about the class details. Make it a method!

Second, your exit condition replaces the current character with a space "to delete wrong path". But if you have found the exit, the path is by definition correct. Don't do that!

Third, you have a bunch of if statements for various character types. That is fine, but please replace them with a single `if` statement using

```
if self.maze_list[row][col] in '|-+*':
    return False
```

Fourth, you wait to mark the current cell with a '*' until after your checks. But you should mark the cell before you declare victory when you reach the exit location. Move the exit test down, I think.

That should clean things up nicely.

Fifth, and finally, your recursive test is backwards. Your code returns `True` when it reached the exit location. Your code returns `False` when it runs into a wall, or tries to cross its own path. Therefore, if the code takes a dead end path, it will reach the end, return false, unroll the recursion a few times, returning false all along, until it gets back.

Thus, if you EVER see a `True` return, you know the code found the exit down that path. You want to immediately return true and do *nothing else*. Certainly don't erase the path - it leads to the exit!

On the other hand, if none of your possible directions return true, then you have found a dead end - the exit does not lie in this direction. You should erase your path, return `False`, and hope that the exit can be found at a higher level.