# python csv importing to link

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get Python to open sites based on a csv file.
I checked all of my code individually to make sure it worked and it does but when I introduce this variable from the csv file I am getting the error message below:
Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

import csv

f = open('gropn1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:

    theurl="http://www.grote.com/?s="+csv_f[1] + "&q1=1"
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

    for partno in soup.find('h2',{"class":"single-product-number"}):
        print(partno)

    for link in soup.find('ul',{"class":"breadcrumbs"}).findAll('a'):
        print(link.text)



f.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grotestart2.py", line 13, in <module>
    theurl="http://www.grote.com/?s="+csv_f[1] + "&q1=1"
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

`csv_f` is your *csv reader instance* and it is actually ["not subscriptable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) by definition.

Did not you mean to use the `row` variable instead. Replace:

```
theurl="http://www.grote.com/?s="+csv_f[1] + "&q1=1"
```

with:

```
theurl="http://www.grote.com/?s="+row[1] + "&q1=1"
```

---

You are also trying to iterate over the results of `soup.find()` call which is a `Tag` instance which is *not iterable.* You meant to use `find_all()`. Replace:

```
for partno in soup.find('h2',{"class":"single-product-number"}):
```

with:

```
for partno in soup.find_all('h2', {"class":"single-product-number"}):
```

Or, a shorter version using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for partno in soup.select('h2.single-product-number'):
```

Comment: Yes the worked - but now I am getting another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PPluck/Downloads/grotestart2.py", line 17, in <module>
    for partsno in soup.find('h2',{"class":"single-product-number"}):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - Any ideas?