# Tic Tac Toe Python GUI 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

i was creating a python tic tac toe game and I'm currently getting the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Workspace\TTT3\src\ttt3.py", line 33, in <lambda>
    self._nwButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._northwest))
  File "E:\Workspace\TTT3\src\ttt3.py", line 13, in checker
     if buttons["image"] == "self.blankPhoto" and xTurn == True:
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not sure what it means exactly, but this is the code I have currently:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
'''xTurn determines whos turn it is, game starts out with X's turn'''
xTurn = True

def checker(buttons):
    global xTurn
    if buttons["image"] == "self.blankPhoto" and xTurn == True:
        print("X's turn")
        xTurn = False
    elif buttons["image"] == "self.blankPhoto" and xTurn == False:
        print("O's turn")
        xTurn = True


class tttGUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):

       '''Setup GUI'''
       Frame.__init__(self)
       self.master.title("Tic-Tac-Toe GUI")
       self.grid()

       self.buttons = StringVar()

       self.blankPhoto = PhotoImage(file = "blank.gif")

       self._nwButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._northwest))
       self._nwButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

       self._nButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._north))
       self._nButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

       self._neButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._northeast))
       self._neButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

       self._wButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._west))
       self._wButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

       self._cButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._center))
       self._cButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

       self._eButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._east))
       self._eButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

       self._swButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._southwest))
       self._swButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

       self._sButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._south))
       self._sButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

       self._seButton = Button(self, image = self.blankPhoto, command = lambda:checker(self._southeast))
       self._seButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    '''Buttons'''
    def _northwest(self):
        print("North-West")


    def _north(self):
        print("North")

    def _northeast(self):
        print("North-East")

    def _west(self):
        print("West")

    def _center(self):
        print("Center")

   def _east(self):
       print("East")

   def _southwest(self):
       print("South-West")

   def _south(self):
       print("South")

   def _southeast(self):
       print("South-East")

def main():
    tttGUI().mainloop()

main()
```

I am trying to make a GUI pop up and whenever you click on one of the buttons it will change to an X or an O depending on whose turn it is.

Comment: It means `buttons` is a method, so `buttons[...]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean? How do you recommend I fix it?

Comment: Maybe *don't* pass a method to `checker`?

Comment: Add () in the lambda function that calls `checker`

Comment: But don't i need to to make that part work?

Comment: @zondo- Do you mean immeditly after lambda? like: lambda()?

Comment: @JacobEss What do you expect checker to do?

Comment: @Natecat it is supposed to check who's turn it is when a button is pressed

Comment: @JacobEss Did you mean to pass in `self.buttons` into it?

Comment: @Natecat pass `self.buttons` into what?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your ping.  I mean `lambda: checker(self._northwest())`

Comment: @zondo In that case it tells me: `Type Error: 'NoneType' object is not suscriptable`

Comment: That means that `self._northwest()` is returning `None`.  All you need to do is make it return something like a dictionary with the `'image'` key.

Comment: @zondo Sorry, I don't quiet understand what you mean by giving it something to return such as a dictionary? Could you give me an example?

Comment: What you probably want to do is make it return `self.buttons`.

Comment: Sorry I know I sound really stupid but what do you mean? Like where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your python says, you are passing the **method** self._something to the function checker().

```
Button( ..., command = lambda: checker(self._northwest))
```

And the methods self._northwest, self._north, ... are not 'subscriptable' object, which means you can't do

```
self._northwest[...]
```

So python fails to evaluate 'if buttons['image'] == ...' and prints that error message.

Besides, according to your code, checker() wants a **instance of tkinter.Button** as an argument, which is subscriptable. So you may have to pass one of your buttons (self._...Button) to the function.

Comment: Yes. Try to fix the Button definitions like "self._nwButton = Button( ..., command = lambda: checker(self._nwButton))". If you wrote checker() (and other parts of the program) correctly, the program may work.

Comment: For further information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not .

Comment: If I am not supposed to do `self._nwButton = Button( ..., command = lambda: checker(self._nwButton))` how else am I supposed to do it. Sorry I am being oblivious, I just don't really understand what you are telling me.

Comment: Ok so I tried doing `self._nwButton = Button( ..., command = lambda: checker(self.buttons))` and it gives me the error `TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Also tried doing `checker(self._..Button)` and no errors but printing anything out.

Comment: @JacobEss It's because two print(...) statements inside checker() are not executed, which means that the conditional statements in 'if ...' and 'elif ...' became False.

Comment: Now let's analyze the reason. If you put "print(self._nwButton['image'])" after "self._nwButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)", you'll see the program prints 'blank.gif'. That means (Button instance)['image'] gives the **name** of the image ('blank.gif'), not the attribute name "self.blankPhoto".

Try to replace buttons['image'] == 'self.blankPhoto' to buttons['image'] == 'blank,gif' in checker(). I confirmed that it works in my computer.

Comment: Odd, mine prints out pyimage1

Comment: @huminpark so that seems to have worked, but now my button images are not updating.