# BeautifulSoup errors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am getting errors when running it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://sport.citifmonline.com/"
url_page_2 = "url" + "2016/10/15/chelsea-3-0-leicester-city-dominant-blues-comfortable-against-champions-photos/"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "wrapper"})

for item in g_data:
    articles = item.content[0].find_all("a", {"class": "cat-box-content"})[0].text
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("h3", {"class": "post-box-title"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What errors? Post the traceback please.

Comment: Not everyone will be willing or able to run your code; but some may still be able to provide help if you show exactly what errors you are getting and describe what you have tried to do already to solve the problem.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 2
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block @Daniel

Comment: after i fixed the indentation error i got this                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 103: character maps to <undefined> @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed `html5lib` (e.g. with `pip install html5lib`), you won't be able to use this parser without getting an error. You could either install it or go e.g. for `"html.parser"` instead which is also mentioned in the [documentation of BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) - just to avoid any errors:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Furthermore, the first line of your inner/second `for` loop throws a `TypeError` because you are trying to index something that is not subscriptable (because it's not a list or something like that, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) for more details). Actually, it's not even existing - the property `content` you're trying to access is `None` (which is of course not subscriptable). You should rather do direct calls of `find_all` on each of the elements:

```
item.find_all(...)
```

Comment: Inb4 pointless downvotes without any constructive criticism. :)

Comment: Probably because `html5lib` is a valid parser so your answer is simply incorrect, the second part of your answer is also wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I did with pip install html5lib.