# Python Datetime Show the Nonetype

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I use pymysql to connect mysql

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect()#I simplified the connecting details

print("date:  {}".format(db.fetchone()[0]))
print("the type of the date: {}".format(type(db.fetchone()[0])))
print("one row : {}".format(db.fetchone()))
print("one row of the type: {}".format(type(db.fetchone())))
print("the recent time:　{}".format(datetime.now()))
print("the recent time of the type:　{}".format(type(datetime.now())))
```

> date:  2017-06-01 10:00:00
>
> the type of the date:  one row :
>
> (datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 31, 17, 0), None, 31.5, 88.7, None)
>
> one row of the type:
>
> the recent time:　2017-06-01 18:31:04.097299
>
> the recent time of the type:

But

```
while ((time - conn.cursor().fetchone()[0] != timedelta(minutes=15))):
    pass
while ((time - datetime.now() != timedelta(minutes=15))):
    pass
```

The former showed up:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Why are't they the same type???

*Update*

MY table:

```
create table weather ( 
                time timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,
                id smallint,
                tpr float(3,1),
                wet float(3,1),
                uv tinyint(2),
                foreign key (id) references chatbot.station(pk));
```

Comment: can you give us more info about where `db` object comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

When we use [`fetchone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) method and no records left to read it returns [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) which is not [subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216980/5997596).

## Example

Assuming that we want to process [non-null](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) `time` values for all records using query

```
SELECT time FROM weather WHERE time IS NOT NULL
```

and `time` object is [current datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)

```
time = datetime.now()
```

then we can write it using [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) coding style like

```
# or any other `datetime` object
time = datetime.now()
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "SELECT time FROM weather WHERE time IS NOT NULL"
    cursor.execute(query)
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    try:
        recorded_time = record[0]
    except TypeError:
        # no records found in table for given query,
        # reporting
        print('No records found for query: "{query}"'
              .format(query=query))
    else:
        while time - recorded_time != timedelta(minutes=15):
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            try:
                recorded_time = record[0]
            except TypeError:
                # no more records found, leaving loop
                break
```

or with checking records for `None`'ness

```
# or any other `datetime` object
time = datetime.now()
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "SELECT time FROM weather WHERE time IS NOT NULL"
    cursor.execute(query)
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    if record is not None:
        recorded_time = record[0]
        while time - recorded_time != timedelta(minutes=15):
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            if record is None:
                # no record found, leaving loop
                break
            recorded_time = record[0]
    else:
        # no records found in table for given query,
        # reporting
        print('No records found for query: "{query}"'
              .format(query=query))
```

## WARNING

Without adding `time IS NOT NULL` filtration we theoretically can get record with `recorded_time` equal to `None`, then difference

```
time - recorded_time
```

will raise `TypeError` since we cannot subtract `None` from `datetime` object.

Comment: @JonathanCheng: completed answer accordingly to your table definition, tell me if it can be improved

Comment: How can I identify the empty table and the none row?thx.Because I want to insert the value if the table is empty and stop insert the value if the time of the row  is None.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `db.fetchone()` returned `None` instead of a datetime object.
Is it possible your loop reached the end of your table?

Comment: instead of a tuple, i guess

Comment: `db.fetchone()` return `tuple`and `db.fetchone()[0]` return `datetim.datetime`

Comment: @JonathanCheng you call it in a loop. does all iterations of the loop behave the same?

Comment: sometimes,so i add the `if db.fetchone() is not None` to fix the exceptioin

Answer (score 1):

Check your returned value for `db.fetchone()`, it seems that is returning a None, you can print it above for example

```
print(db.fetchone()[0])
```

make a print inside the while loop (is just a quick way, not always the best way is doing this), some of your values must be None, if only one is, the code breaks.

> Solution

You can ask before do the minus math operation if your value is none or not, If it's not, do the maths, if it is do nothing