# How do I fix the 'type' is not subscriptable error in line "if target == list[middle]" for python 3.6.3?

Tags: python-3.6

Attempting to sort a list and then determine whether an user input is in list and I am continually getting an error in the recursive binary search.

```
def main():
    list = ['Paul', 'Aaron', 'Jacob', 'James', 'Bill', 'Sara', 'Cathy', 
'Barbara', 'Amy', 'Jill']
    print("Unsorted list:")
    print(list)
    bubbleSort(list)
    print("Sorted list:")
    print(list)
    binarySearch()
```

This is where I am sorting the list

```
def bubbleSort(list): #sorting of the list
    firstUnsorted = 0
    swapped = True
    while firstUnsorted < len(list) and swapped:
        index = len(list)-1
        swapped = False
        while index > firstUnsorted:
            if list[index] < list[index-1]:
                swap(list, index-1, index)
                swapped = True
            index = index-1
        firstUnsorted = firstUnsorted + 1

def swap(list, index1, index2):
    temp = list[index1]
    list[index1] = list[index2]
    list[index2] = temp
```

This is the second part of the recursive binary search and the section I am getting my error

```
def recursiveBSearch(names, target, first, last): 
    if first > last:
        return False
    else:
        middle = int((first + last)/2)
        if target == list[middle]: #this is where I am getting on my error
            return True
        else:
            if target < list[middle]: #this is where I am getting the error
                recursiveBSearch(first, middle-1)
            else:
                recursiveBSearch(middle + 1, last)
```

This is the first part of the recursive binary search

```
def binarySearch(): #first part of recursive binary search
    names = [list]
    aName = input("enter a name to be found: ")
    first = 0
    last = len(names)-1
    if recursiveBSearch(names, aName, first, last):
        print(aName, "was found")
    else:
        print(aName, "was not found")
```

Comment: Have you tried not calling your variable `list` (it's a reserved keyword)?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue so far? Have you tried running just that method without recursion to see if it does what you want? Have you tried printing out the input parameters to make sure your variables are what you think they are? Try to simplify your issue with a [mcve] and it'll be easier to see what's going on, instead of running the entire program at once.

Comment: As explained in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not), you can understand what subcriptable means. Most likely, the variable `list` isn't what you think it is when you reference it.