# 'TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable' in binary searches

Tags: typeerror, binary-search

For schoolwork I have to do binary searches, I followed the steps but I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "X:/Computer
>   Science/Python/February 2018/25 02 18/binary searching.py", line 15,
>   in 
>       end = aList.index[middle] TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Here is my code:

```
aList = [3,13,24,27,31,39,45,60,69]
end = len(aList) - 1
found = 0
start = 0

target = int(input("Please input the item you would like to search for:\t>"))
while start <= end and found == 0:
    middle = int((start + end) / 2)

    if aList[middle] == target:
        found = 1
        print(target , "is in the list.")

    if target < aList[middle]:
        end = aList.index[middle]
    else:
        start = aList.index[middle]
if found == 0:
    print("The search item was not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

See here [In Python, what does it mean if an object is subscriptable or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not#)

and I paraphrase: "[to be subscriptable object must] implement the **getitem**() method"

`index[middle]` means "pull the value from dictionary `index` that has key equals to the value of variable `middle`"

Line 15 should look like as bellow - a function call:

> end = aList.index(middle)