# How to correctly wrap a dict in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Sometimes it's nice to be able to use a dictionary like an object (so that you don't have to always write `mydict['blah']`.  Instead, you can write `mydict.blah`

In Python 3, there are new rules about overriding/wrapping a python dictionary.  In Python2, it was enough to wrap the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods. When you wrap these things, you get some nice capabilities to add some special handling when a certain attribute was added (e.g. you could clean/filter data in/out of a dict).

A situation where this is helpful is in a Flask template (an HTML template).  Using a `__getattr__` filter, you can format data as it leaves the `dict`.  This way, in the template (where Python expressions can look a little complex) you can keep things simple in there by just writing `mymodel.blah` and knowing that the text coming out of `blah` is already the way you want it.

In Python3 wrapping a `dict` is a little messy.  I"m not sure how to make it work now.  Here are two rough implementations that are not working well:

```
# messed up Python3 wrapped dictionary (sets work, but gets do not)
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
        self.clean_strings()
    def clean_strings(self):
        for key, value in self.items():
            self[key] = string_empty_to_none(value)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        #this never gets called in Python 3
        return self[name]
```

Here's another one:

```
# sets don't work - Always throws: TypeError: 'AttrDict' object does not support item assignment
class AttrDict():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = dict()
        self.data.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.clean_strings()
    def clean_strings(self):
        for key, value in self.data.items():
            self.data[key] = string_empty_to_none(value)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.data:
            return self.data[attr]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("--%r object has no attribute %r" % (type(self).__name__, attr)) 
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'data':
            super(AttrDict, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            self.data[name] = value
```

Here's what my little utility method looks like:

```
def string_empty_to_none(s):
    if type(s) == str:
            return None if (s.strip() == '') else s

    return s
```

I know that in Python3, you are supposed to use `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`  But that always seems to end up in an infinite loop when I do this.

NOTE: that the final syntax that I'm looking for is like this:

```
>>> x = AttrDict({'some': 'value'})
>>> x['blah'] = 'hello world'
>>> print(x.blah)
hello world
>>> print(x.some)
value
```

Comment: A Python 2 implementation should work fine without modification on Python 3. There are no new rules about wrapping dicts. Your messed-up implementations fail on Python 3, but they also fail on Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by overwriting using `__getitem__` within `__getattr__`.

```
class AttrDict(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return super().__getitem__(item)

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        return super().__setitem__(item, value)


x = AttrDict({'some': 'value'})
x['blah'] = 'hello world'
print(x.blah)  # hello world
print(x.some)  # value

# you can also assign value this way
x.foo = 'bar'
print(x['foo'])   # bar
```

Comment: How would you improve my `__init__` in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need to do `self.__dict__` assignments within the `__init__` method of a `dict`-inherited class - just do the usual arg-passing to `super()` and then your processing. Actually i am not even sure what `self.__dict__ = self` implies - i can imagine that it will break some internal behaviour of dicts if you are overriding their `__dict__` (even with "their`self`es").

Also it is better to modifiy the `__getattr__` method, since this will be the fallback method for Python if `__getattribute__` could not find anything. On the other hand, if you know that you're about to use most of the time the property-style accessor, then you could switch that logic.

See the following examples:

```
def string_empty_to_none(s):
  if type(s) == str:
    return None if (s.strip() == '') else s
  return s

# This will always have issues, even in IDE's
print('AttrDict')
class AttrDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__dict__ = self
    self.clean_strings()
  def clean_strings(self):
    for key, value in self.items():
      self[key] = string_empty_to_none(value)

test = AttrDict({'a': 1})
test['x'] = 2
test.z = ""
print(test.a)
print(test['a'])
print(test.x)
print(test['x'])
print(test.z)
print(test['z'])


print('MostlyPropertiesAccessDict')
class MostlyPropertiesAccessDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # No need for the self.__dict__ part
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.clean_strings()

  def clean_strings(self):
    for key, value in self.items():
      self[key] = string_empty_to_none(value)

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if not name in self:
      raise AttributeError(
        "Attribute {} does not exist".format(name))
    return self[name]

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self[name] = string_empty_to_none(value)

  def __delattr__(self, name):
    if not name in self:
      raise AttributeError(
        "Attribute {} does not exist".format(name))
    del self[name]

test2 = MostlyPropertiesAccessDict({'a': 1})
test2['x'] = 2
test2.z = ""
print(test2.a)
print(test2['a'])
print(test2.x)
print(test2['x'])
print(test2.z)
print(test2['z'])

print("MostlyKeysAccessDict")
class MostlyKeysAccessDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # No need for the self.__dict__ part
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.clean_strings()

  def clean_strings(self):
    for key, value in self.items():
      self[key] = string_empty_to_none(value)

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if not name in self:
      raise AttributeError(
        "Attribute {} does not exist".format(name))
    return self[name]

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return super().__getattribute__(name)

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self[name] = string_empty_to_none(value)

  def __delattr__(self, name):
    if not name in self:
      raise AttributeError(
        "Attribute {} does not exist".format(name))
    del self[name]

test3 = MostlyKeysAccessDict({'a': 1})
test3['x'] = 2
test3.z = ""
print(test3.a)
print(test3['a'])
print(test3.x)
print(test3['x'])
print(test3.z)
print(test3['z'])
```

Comment: Great answer.  The other answer (@bubble...) uses getitem/setitem.  Is there any advantage to your method?  Thank you for explaining how `__init__` could be improved.

Comment: In general it does not really matter if you retrieve the values over `__getItem__(name)` or `self[name]` (same for `__setItem__(name, value)` and `self[name] = value`) the latter always calls the former internally in Python - and is the default way of not using internals when not needed for a specific reason. What actually did matter was the part with `__init__`. Also updated the code that when adding a value that it does your empty string check.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a wrapper class that contains a dictionary and then implement `__getitem__`:

```py
class DictionaryWrapper():

    _dict = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._dict[item]

    @attribute
    def key1(self):
        return self._dict["key1"]
```

Now, you can treat your DictionartWrapper as a dictionary. (This limited implementation only allows reading.)

```py
my_dictionary = DictionaryWrapper()
print(my_dictionary["key1"])
```

If the keys in your dictionary are known, you could even expose their values via attributes on the wrapper class.

```py
print(my_dictionary.key1)
```

For a similar discussion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216980/4093278).