# Python 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
data2 = data.drop('Indicator Name', axis=1, inplace=True)
data3 = data2.drop('Indicator Code', axis=1, inplace=True)
x = [ data3[x].mean() for x in data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]]
y = data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]
plt.plot(x, y, color='orange')

plt.title('GDP Per year form 1960 to 2017')
plt.show()
```

I want to plot the mean value of all the data from 1960 to 2017 but I'm getting an error when I try to get the mean values for each column to use them in the plot. What is the best approach to achieve that. Need help

```
 TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-63-ec5963e0529b> in <module>()
       1 data2 = data.drop('Indicator Name', axis=1, inplace=True)
       2 data3 = data.drop('Indicator Code', axis=1, inplace=True)
 ----> 3 x = [ data2[x].mean() for x in data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]]
       4 y = data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]
       5 plt.plot(x, y, color='orange')





<ipython-input-63-ec5963e0529b> in <listcomp>(.0)
          1 data2 = data.drop('Indicator Name', axis=1, inplace=True)
          2 data3 = data.drop('Indicator Code', axis=1, inplace=True)
    ----> 3 x = [ data2[x].mean() for x in data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]]
          4 y = data.loc[:, "1960" : "2017" ]
          5 plt.plot(x, y, color='orange')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Use a debugger and find out which object is considered to be NoneType. In python NoneType means Null.

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) helps. Essentially I suspect that `data2` is None here, due to the use of `inplace=True`.