# getting error in pygame 'pygame.surface' object is not subscript able

Tags: python, pygame

I'm getting this error when running `pygame.Surface` object is not subscriptable. I have tried looking at similar code but still to green to place where I went wrong.

if I remove all "hit" lines it works. I want to insert an image for a hit function it will run till SPACE is hit.

```
 elif self.isHitRight:
            win.blit(hitRight[self.hitCount], (self.x, self.y))
            self.hitCount += 1
        elif self.isHitLeft:
            win.blit(hitLeft[self.hitCount], (self.x, self.y))
            self.hitCount += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please make sure that, when asking a question, you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This will help us figure out where the problem might be in your code.

Comment: Can you also please provide the full error trace?

Comment: This message likely means that the `[]` operator is not defined for `hitRight`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, what does it mean if an object is subscriptable or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Your error `object is not subscriptable` means that you have tried to use an array operator (that is you've done something like `x[y]`) on an object that does not support it. The only objects you're doing this on are `hitLeft` and `hitRight`, which I presume are `pygame.Surface` objects. [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects don't support this.

Most likely you originally needed to define `hitLeft` and `hitRight` as arrays of `pygame.Surface` objects.