# error 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: pandas

I am getting the error  'method' object is not subscriptable . Please tell me about this error ? and what is the problem in my code ?

```
def answer_five():
    census = census_df.copy()
    census.set_index['STNAME]
    return (census['COUNTY']).argmax()
answer_five()
```

Comment: change `set_index['STNAME]` to `set_index('STNAME')` ..?

Comment: can you explain when we get this error of ' method 'object is not subscriptable

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not

Answer (score 0):

```
census.set_index(['STNAME'])
```

Try this code on place of  `census.set_index['STNAME]`