# I am trying to perform the Euler method in python but I am getting a 'type error', why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to solve an ODE in python using the Euler method but I am getting the
"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" error when I call the function. Here's my code:

```
##Parameters
g = 9.8 #in m/s^2
l = 0.5 #in m
omega0 = np.sqrt(g/l)

def euler(theta0, w0, deltat, t_end):
    t0 = 0 #in s

    ##Constructing the arrays
    t_arr = np.arange(t0, t_end + deltat, deltat)
    w = np.zeros(len(t_arr)) #angular velocity in rad/s
    theta = np.zeros(len(t_arr))

    ##Setting up our initial conditions
    w[0] = w0
    theta = theta0

    ##Performing the Euler method for both small and large angles
    for i in range(len(t_arr) -1):
       w[i + 1] = w[i] - ((omega0)**2)*np.sin(theta[i])*deltat
       theta[i + 1] = theta[i] + w[i]*deltat


    return theta


euler(0.07, 0, 0.05, 5)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `theta = theta0`. Seem `theta0` is a float instead of an array. `np.full_like` or `np.ones_like` may be helpful.

Comment: Aaron probably has the right of it, and you should definitely follow Michael's advice in the future.

Also look into using `pdb`, or a similar python debugger (as simple as `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), which will let you step through your code and examine variables to solve these sorts of issues on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to set `theta[0] = theta0` when you set the initial conditions (line 16), but instead you redefined theta to be a float by just writing `theta = theta0`, instead of the np.zeros array you had previously made it in line 12. Change that and it will work.

The 'not subscriptable' TypeError is not a particularly easy-to-understand way of explaining the error. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) if you want more details about what that means. The most up-voted answer is:

> It basically means that the object implements the **getitem**() method. In other words, it describes objects that are "containers", meaning they contain other objects. This includes strings, lists, tuples, and dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines

```
    theta = np.zeros(len(t_arr))
...
    theta = theta0
```

close to each other do not make sense and indicate a misunderstanding in their meaning because both put a value in the variable `theta`.  I.e. that the first one is without any effect.  The second line is the only one which is relevant.

I *assume* that the variable `theta` should hold a `numpy` array.  But what you pass in the call of the last line as the value for the parameter `theta0` is a mere float value, so that contradicts.

I *guess* that you might want to put the `theta0` into the first field of the just created array `theta`:

`theta[0] = theta0`

Probably then it works.