# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in list in python

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling

I am getting the TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable on the line `sig_data = sig_data[0:file_length_num]` in the following code -

```
def create_slice_from_wav(file_path, file_len, slice_len, step_size):
  #read in wav file
  samp_freq, sig_data = sf.read(file_path)
  
  #convert file_length from min to sample numbers
  file_length_num = 5*samp_freq*60
  
  #convert slice_len from ms to sample numbers
  slice_sample_num = slice_len*samp_freq/1000
  
  #use only slices within file_length
  sig_data = sig_data[0:file_length_num]
  
  #determine number of samples and length
  n_samples = sig_data.shape[0]
  sig_len = n_samples/samp_freq
  print('Length: ' + str(sig_len) + ' sec')
```

Comment: try looking at the output of `type(sig_data)`, it is most likely an integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it look like `sf.read()` will output the data on the first element of the return tuple and the sample rate on the second. This means that you have reversed the tuple order.

If you change your code to be `sig_data, samp_freq = sf.read(file_path)` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In Python (and all programming languages that I know of), it is not possible to specify an index for integer data types.
You may assume that `sig_data` is read in as a list (or tuple) but in reality, it was captured as an integer.
You are getting that error because your variable `sig_data` evaluates to an integer.

Can you share the contents of your file?

Comment: He just reversed the return tuple on his code. Look at my answer and you will see the proper solution.

Comment: Thank you @jpnadas for the clarification. It appears I only addressed the symptoms, but you were able to find the cure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though `sig_data` is an int in your code. And you can not iterate over an int, it has to be a list/array of ints or such.

Answer (score 0):

Here, sig_data is an integer but I assume that you have thought of sig_data as a list. The problem comes from the fact that you are not allowed to slice an integer thus giving you an error. The type of sig_data can easily be found using type(sig_data); you will find that it is an int.

NOTE: If you do not understand what subscriptable means then check this out:
[What does it mean if a Python object is "subscriptable" or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)