# What order do JavaScripts need to be written in Python?

Tags: javascript

**Update**

Thank you Chris and Taplar for providing the following links -

[www.getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction](http://www.getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction)
[load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

I did not look at the documentation in the first place because I did not have enough grasp of the issue, to even know what part of the documentation to search in.

**Original Question**

I had many issues when adding my date widget to my customer user profile model, you can see more of my code relating to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347615/getting-date-widget-to-display-american-dates-for-american-users/63348193?noredirect=1#comment112026150_63348193). One issue was related to the order of my Java Scripts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-z0oKYg6xiLq3yJGsp/LsY9XykbweQlHl42jHv2XTBz4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If I put my scripts the other way round, the date widget would not work.

It never dawned on me that the order the scripts were in would have an impact on whether the code worked or not.

Would an experienced Python programmer be able to tell, just by looking at the two scripts, what order they need to be in?

To prevent future problems, is there anything I can check, to work out what orders script need to be written in?

Comment: Bootstrap requires jquery so jquery need to be executed first.
You cannot use variables before declaration in every language. I don't know python is related here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python or Django.  JavaScript code is evaluated in the browser, and in the order in which it's included.  If a script has a dependency on another script, then it needs to come after that other script.

Comment: You can work out the order by reading the library's documentation.

Comment: ↑ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

Comment: David I encountered the problem while using Django which is why I added the Python and Django tags, I have now removed these.

Comment: Thank you Taplar and Chris for providing links. I have read the links and now have a better grasp on the issue.

Comment: Hey Ross 

Would you mind sharing some of the code behind your date widget? Were you using the date widget for DOB or something else?

Comment: I have talked about my date widget here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347615/getting-date-widget-to-display-american-dates-for-american-users/63348193?noredirect=1#comment112026150_63348193

Comment: I was making a customer user registration model and wanted to include a DOB field.

Answer (score 5):

The libraries must be included in that order, as the bootstrap file is a plugin for the base library of jQuery.  Without the base library already included, the addon has nothing that it can add-on to.