# How to resolve -'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am fetching some data from an API and saving the contents of response JSON to a list.
However i am getting "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error. I understood that i am indexing a none object. How do i resolve it? I am pretty new to Python.

```
for i in range(0,len(content)):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({
   "GetSignificantDevelopments_Request_1": {
      "FindRequest": {
         "CompanyIdentifiers_typehint": [
            "CompanyIdentifiers"
         ],
         "CompanyIdentifiers": [
            {
               "RIC": {
                  #"Value": content[i]
                  "Value": "8341.T"
               }
            }
         ],
         "StartDate": "2020-08-01T00:00:00",
         "EndDate": "2020-09-21T00:00:00",
         "Significance": "1 2 3",
         "MaxNumberOfItems": 2000
      }
   }
}), headers=headers)
        data=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
        for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
            list_RepNo=[]
            list_DevelopmenId=[]
            list_RepNo.append(item['Xrefs']['RepNo'])
            list_DevelopmenId.append(item['Xrefs']['DevelopmentId'])
    except Exception as Error:
    print(Error)
    raise
    continue
```

The error which i am getting is below:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c73ee1d65472> in <module>
     36 }), headers=headers)
     37         data=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
---> 38         for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
     39             list_RepNo=[]
     40             list_DevelopmenId=[]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Okay, it's good that you understood that. But it's not clear who do you want by "resolve" it. The data simply does not have that field, that's why the value is none.

Comment: only logical solution, without getting into details in your code, is to wrap the subscript access with check that it is not None, something like: `if data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1'] is not None and data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse'] is not None:` - the order of the check is critical because you first want to check the first access, to make sure it safe, and secondly the second one.

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) ! might help you to understand the problem u are facing !

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). One of the keys in this chain (`data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']`) doesn't exist, so you get `None` when you try to access it. `None` is not a `dict` or `list`-type, so you can't obtain anything at a subscript of `None`. In other words, `None['...']` is invalid. To fix it, use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) or [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the array you are indexing is of `None` type.

In your case, if you do

```py
In[1]: type(data)
```

you would get

```py
Out[1]: <class 'NoneType'>
```

**Solution:**

You would have to make sure the array(data in your case) being indexed is not of type `None`.