# object is not subscriptable fix?

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
import sqlite3                                                                                      
                                                                                                    
db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')                                                                 
cursor = db.cursor()                                                                                
                                                                                                    
sqx = "SELECT Login_Status FROM login WHERE Username = ? AND Login_Status = ?"                      
cursor.execute(sqx, ('Test', '1'))                                                                  
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]                                                                       
                                                                                                    
if result[0] == '2':                                                                                
     print('Order is complete')                                                                     
else:                                                                                               
     print('order is active')
```

I'm new to `python` and this is probably a easy fix, but I don't understand. And I looked it up, but the results I get are confusing.

I hope you guys can figure it out and help me understand.

Comment: change this from `result[0]` to just `result` in if condition

Answer (score 0):

For objects that are "containers" it means the object does not implement `__getitem__`, so it does not support access using the square brackets notation `(x = my_obj[y])`

In your case the `results[0]` may not exist

Try this

```
cursorObj.execute('SELECT Login_Status FROM login WHERE ...')
 
rows = cursorObj.fetchall()
 
for row in rows:
 
    print(row)
```

See if you get some results and move from there

Comment: Accessing an empty container would raise a subclass of `LookupError`.  "Object is not subscriptable" means the the object does not implement `__getitem__`, that is it does not support access using the square brackets notation (`x = my_obj[y]`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I updated the answer