# Error : Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Member' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I am trying to make a `give` command but each time I run it, it gives me this problem: *Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Member' object is not subscriptable*. Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def givecoke(message, amount, memberuser: discord.Member):
  await open_account(message.author)
  user = message.author
  users = await get_bank_data()

  memberuser[str(user.id)]["Roblox Coke"] += amount
  user[str(user.id)]["Roblox Code"] -= amount



  em = discord.Embed(title = f"Done!",color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff))
  await message.send(embed=em)

  with open("db.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
```

this is at the bottom of my code

````
async def open_account(user):

  users = await get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else: 
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    #thanks
    users[str(user.id)]["thanks"] = 0

    #tradeable stuff
    users[str(user.id)]["B737"] = 1
    users[str(user.id)]["B747"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["B757"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["B767"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["B777"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["B787"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["BombardierCRJ700"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["Concorde"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["MC-DC10"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["MC-DC11"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["A320"] = 1
    users[str(user.id)]["A330"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["A340"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["A350"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["A380"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["Cookie"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["Roblox Coke"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["Coffee"] = 0


  with open("db.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
  with open("db.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    
  return users


async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
  users = await get_bank_data()

  users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

  with open("db.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)

  bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
  return bal```
````

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana I have. That is the full error traceback

Comment: I think you need to assign `open_account()` to a variable and replace that and `users` with `memberuser` and `user`.

Comment: @12944qwerty, `open_account()` is already assigned at the bottom of my code. If I replace it it wont get how many `cokes` there are to give to the user.

Comment: You're not assigning the return value to a variable....

Comment: @12944qwerty So then, how do I do that? `open_account() = [str(user.id)]["Roblox Coke"]`?

Comment: A variable should be declared the same way as you did `users = await get_bank_data()`

Comment: I don't understand. @12944qwerty

Comment: How do you normally assign variables?

Comment: Like you said. Its just that on the bottom of my code I have this: (im editing the question @12944qwerty)

Comment: You're talking about defining methods, not assigning variables. Variables are in this format `var = something`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean if a Python object is "subscriptable" or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Comment: @jhoepken No that doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to subscript, `memberuser` and `user` although they are member objects:

```py
  memberuser[str(user.id)]["Roblox Coke"] += amount
  user[str(user.id)]["Roblox Code"] -= amount
```

If your trying to get the id of these, you can do memberuser.id, and then to insert them into your dictionary (which is a global variable users, not good btw) you can do

```py
if user.id in users:
    users[user.id]["Roblox Coke"] += amount
else:
    ... # insert the user into your dictionary
```

Also, I recommend using a database such as [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com) with [motor](https://pypi.org/project/motor/)

Comment: What do you mean by ... # insert the user into your dictionary. ?

Comment: If it hits the else statments, it means that the user isnt in the `users` dictionary, so I suggest inserting them into it, or telling them to do something to let them do so!

Comment: Would I have to insert every single user id in the server ?

Comment: and how would I store the users into the dict? It would be user.id = 0123891723891273?

Comment: No only the user that is sending the message, in this case user.id, should look something like this: `users[user.id] = { 'Roblox Code' : amount}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, `memberuser` is a discord.Member, but you do this:

```py
  memberuser[str(user.id)]["Roblox Coke"] += amount
```

Subscriptable means you can use `[]` on, so discord.Member is not subscriptable.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to. Answerer was showing you the mistake.