# Hi everyone, I really do not understand this error " None type object is not suscriptable"

Tags: kivy, kivymd

None type object suscriptable. I really don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: You probably have some code that tries to access an element of a list, but the list variable has a value of `None`. E.g. `something[2]`. The same would apply for any subscriptable object, e.g. a dictionary. Without seeing any code it's impossible to know. See [What does it mean if a Python object is "subscriptable" or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Comment: No one can tell you where your mistake is without seeing your mistake. Please post a [mcve].