# Get text from html element using selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

From the HTML code below I want to get the text of 1 and 2 separately.

```
<div class="sc-492bf320-0 sc-7d450bff-9 crIwBV juiSXn">
  <div data-change-key="homeScore.display" class="sc-18688171-0 sc-7d450bff-4 fXAhuT fBSHnS">2</div>
  <div data-change-key="awayScore.display" class="sc-18688171-0 sc-7d450bff-4 fXAhuT fBSHnS">1</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
home_score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.sc-492bf320-0.sc-7d450bff 9.crIwBV.juiSXn")[0].text
away_score = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.sc-492bf320-0.sc-7d450bff 9.crIwBV.juiSXn")[1].text
```

I am getting an error that `TypeError: 'WebElement'` object is not subscriptable.

What can I change to get the texts separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `find_element` not `find_elements` (notice the trailing `s`). For the former a single WebElement is returned. For the latter, a List of WebElements is returned. A list is a container and is subscriptable (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216972/4720957)). A WebElement is not a container like List or Tuple. Hence you cannot use the subscriptable notation `[int]`.

Second, `div.sc-492bf320-0.sc-7d450bff 9.crIwBV.juiSXn` -- this CSS selector would fail. It would not give you anything. Remove space before 9 and replace it with a dot (`.`). More info on using CSS selectors correctly [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).