# TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I have an error on my Pygame Project here is the code

```py
def text(window, text, loc, color, font_size):
    font = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Sticky_koala-Regular.ttf', font_size)
    
    text = font.render(text, True, color)

    window.blit(text, loc)

    return (text)
```

```py
text(window, "/" + numerictext(maxvariable), (variablebox[0][0] + variablebox[1], popuprect.top + 80), (255, 255, 255), 36)
```

Answer (score 1):

As showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216980/19288094), the error `object is not subscriptable` means that you're trying to use a pygame surface as a container. From what you've showed to us the only place there is this kind of instance is the moment you are calling the function:

```
text = drawText(
    window,                                                    #surface where to blit the string
    "/" + numerictext(maxvariable),                            #string to render
    (variablebox[0][0] + variablebox[1], popuprect.top + 80),  #tuple of int of the location of the text on the window
    (255, 255, 255),                                           #color of the rendered text
    36)                                                        # dimension of the text
```

So, if the error shows up in the slice of code you shared, has to be in the `loc`, calling one of `variablebox[0][0]` or `variablebox[1]`