# "object type is not subscriptable" error iterating a list

Tags: python

> 6.3 Assign the value 5 to the variable guess_me. Use a for loop to iterate a variable called number over range(10). If number is less than guess_me, print 'too low'. If it equals guess_me, print found it! and then break out of the for loop. If number is greater than guess_me, print 'oops' and then exit the loop.

I will include what I have so far as well as the error message.

```
guess_me = 5
number = [10]

for number in range[1,10]:

    if number < guess_me:
        print("too low")
        number += 1

    elif number == guess_me:
        print("found it!")
        break

    else:
        print("oops")
        exit
```

line 4

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I just don't get how I'm supposed to write line 4.
I tried it a few other ways, like using an i for index and avoiding the variable "number" and the other error I got was "indices must be int or... not tuple", but I never had anything written as a tuple, at least nothing with (#).

Comment: `range(1,10)` is what you need

Comment: Compare the syntax you've used to what's _in the instructions_. Brackets, braces and parentheses are not interchangable.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it had to be in brackets.

Comment: You do not need to declare `number = [10]` at the top, so delete this statement. number is implicitly declared in the for statement. Also note that you do NOT have to increment number when looping though range(1,10). Remove the line `number += 1`

Answer (score 2):

Here you're writing in range 1 to 10 as a subscript [1,10]. Something that is subscriptable is something that has a list/string/dict of numbers or characters that can be indexed.

As said in: [What does it mean if a Python object is "subscriptable" or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

For example the string `"montypython"` is subscriptable since its a list of characters. So if I were to call the index 3 of montypython like `"montypython"[3]` you would get `'t'`.

So here you the object `range` cannot be subscriptable. The correct notation is:

```
for number in range(1,10)
```