# 'TestCase' object is not subscriptable ->RobotFramework Listener

Tags: robotframework, listener

I am trying to use a Listener to save data from mi test case (Develop in robotFramework)so i develop this Listener:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import psycopg2
import datetime

class CustomListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3 
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host= "....",
            port= "...",
            database = "...s",
            user = "j....",
            password = "......")
        

    def end_test (self, data, result):
        if result ['status'] == "PASS":
            execution_result='PASSED'
        else:
            execution_result= 'FALLIED'
            
        test_name = result['name']
        execution_start = result['start_time']
        execution_end = result['end_time']
        execution_duration = result['elapsedtime']
        
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO test_results (test_name, excecution_star, execution_end, execution_duration, execution_result) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (test_name, execution_start, execution_end, execution_duration.total_seconds(), execution_duration)
        )
        
        self.conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

On eclipse I develop mi testCase and I run it whit this configuration:
run as -> Additional Robot Frameworks arguments: --listener CustomListener.py

The test Case get Pass, but i get this ERROR :

ERROR ] Calling method 'end_test' of listener 'C:\Users\voztelecom\Documents\CustomListener.py' failed: TypeError: 'TestCase' object is not subscriptable

Does anyone know what could be happening?

I expect this  data be save on mi Postgres DataBase.

I tri change the def end_test (self, data, result): for def end_test (self, data, attrs):

```
def end_test(self, name, attrs):
    # Accede a los atributos del objeto attrs correctamente
    test_status = attrs['status']
    test_name = attrs['longname']
    execution_start = attrs['starttime']
    execution_end = attrs['endtime']
    execution_duration = attrs['elapsedtime
```

Dont work-

I try adding a setting.robot file with adding the path for where I have mi CustomListener.py file-

Its still donsnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean if a Python object is "subscriptable" or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

`result` is instance of robot.result.model.TestCase class. You are referencing it like it as a dict.  If you check the examples of the listener documentation, those show example that you should use dot notation:

```py
if result.status  == "PASS":
  execution_result='PASSED'
else:
  execution_result= 'FALLIED'

test_name = result.name
execution_start = result.start_time
execution_end = result.end_time
execution_duration = result.elapsedtime
```

Documentation; https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/extending_robot_framework/listeners_prerun_api/listeners#example-listeners